# VideoView Initial display causes layout to expand length of screen

Tags: android

everyone. I have a project where I need to display a video within a VideoView in portrait orientation, but I've been running into a weird issue for the last couple weeks. Also note, this issue only occurs the first time the VideoView is loaded with data.

This is a very stripped version of the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
       <VideoView /> <-- W:fill_parent, H:wrap_content
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now for the actual issue: when the VideoView is first loaded with data, both its height/width fill the entire screen (minus the padding space) for less than a second (up to 3 seconds, depending on whether it's local or streaming), then it magically adjusts itself to the intended size.

Since it takes longer for videos not stored locally, I feel as if the issue has to do with the VideoView taking time to load the video, and not adjusting its boundaries correctly immediately, which is why it expands to fill the screen, then suddenly drops down to the appropriate size.

Now, I believe the reason it doesn't do that every time is because it's still using the same instance of the VideoView each time it's loaded (since it's using a ViewFlipper and not setContentView, it's not creating a new instance of it).

However, I'm loading the data into the VideoView in the same way, and I don't understand why the issue doesn't persist, which makes me think my assumption of why it's doing that is wrong.

Now for what I've tried:

I started with a width of fill_parent and height of wrap_content for both the RelativeLayout and the VideoView, which is where I noticed this problem initially. Also note: the graphic layout in Eclipse shows the same issue with these settings that I'm trying to solve: the VideoView is expanded to fill the screen, minus the padding it has).

I've tried forcing the layout to a specific pixel dimension in the XML layout (terrible, I know), and then defining new LayoutParams for the views and setting them after the video has been properly loaded.

I've tried creating a new VideoView dynamically and adding it to the layout after it's been loaded; still no luck.

And now I'm out of ideas... Anyone else have some?

And thanks in advance for your help~

**EDIT:**

As a workaround in the meantime, I created an onPreparedListener() for the VideoView, and keep the view hidden until the onPreparedListener is fired off. That seems to solve the problem, but I'm more curious as to why the VideoView was doing what it's doing, not necessarily just how to fix it.

Thanks again~

Comment: We've come across a similar-sounding problem, but were unable to work out how to keep the view hidden - how did you manage that?

Comment: It actually didn't work; I just didn't update the post. If the VideoView is hidden, the system won't prepare it until it's made visible again. So instead, I forced it to a small static size, loaded the video, and then let it resize based on its boundaries

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Yes, we're trying that.  We still get a noticeable show-then-resize effect.  We'll keep plugging.

Comment: Yeah, that was the downside to the approach, but I wasn't able to come up with a better solution for it, sadly